# Configuring NGINX with a user list http header/user?

Tags: nginx, pki

I've got an nginx config that does ssl-pki authentication - I'm happily able to authenticate my users.

However, I want to take it a bit further - I want to allow/deny access to resources based on the ssl variables - specifically `$ssl_client_s_dn` (and verify that `$ssl_client_verify` is 'SUCCESS')

Based on this I want to selectively allow/deny groups of URLs based on a user list. In this scenario, Elasticsearch. I have:

- Some common APIs I want to access (server status, cluster health, 'ping').
- Some indicies I want one group of users to be able to 'see'
- Some indices I want another group of users to 'see'.

Now it looks like I can *probably* do this with [`http_auth_request`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) - redirect to an 'auth' url - a bit like outlined in [this blog](https://developers.shopware.com/blog/2015/03/02/sso-with-nginx-authrequest-module/)

But this seems a bit overkill to me, as to do that I'll have to write my own 'engine' to accept/read http, validate it against what amounts to a regex, and spit out a response code.

What I'm trying to do 'whitelist' e.g. for me:

```
allow if /(logstash|filebeat|topbeat)-mygroup-.*/;
```

(where 'mygroup' is read from a file somewhere, and ideally allows to have multiple-group membership).

Now, is this best done with `http_auth_request`, and feeding it to a really cut down validator web app (either script standalone, or a cgi type script inside NGINX) or is there a better way?

This module is an extra for nginx, which means a recompile. That's not a disaster, but if it's not necessary (and I can continue using 'stock' nginx) that would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this would work. Given a file path, it will return a "Forbidden" response unless `$ssl_client_verify` has been set appropriately.

```
location ^~ /(logstash|filebeat|topbeat) {
   if ($ssl_client_verify != "SUCCESS") {
    return 403;
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this already, by requiring client verification. I'm trying for something a little more fine grained - an admin user should be able to access admin APIs, and a user in a group should be able to access indices (urls) matching that group name.

Comment: That kind of logic is nearly always handled at an application level, not a web-server level. Projects like Node.js merge the app-logic and web-server logic, so handling this with something like Node.js or another backend application server would be a natural fit.